# btnSearch2.setOnClickListener(this); give a error

Tags: java, android

I'm learning android studio and trying to make simple dictionary. But when i start to app `btnSearch2.setOnClickListener(this);` this code gives a error and app crashes ( button and button2 are in different fragment ). What should i do?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

and this is the variables I defined

```
 EditText editTextSearch;
 Button btnSearch;
 TextView txtResults;
 EditText editTextSearch2;
 Button btnSearch2;
 TextView txtResults2;


    editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtSearch);
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    txtResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewResults );
    editTextSearch2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtSearch2);
    btnSearch2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    txtResults2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewResults2 );
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSearch2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

lastly this is my code.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
           //my code
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
         //my code
              break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your two buttons (button and button2) are in different fragments (as you said) and you are fetching ids in an Activity whose layout didn't contain any buttons with that specific ids. So the value of `btnSearch` and `btnSearch2` is `null`. So that's why when you are applying click listener the app is crashing because values are null.
Either make buttons in activity's layout or fetch ids and do your business logic in fragment instead of Activity.

You can take reference from this site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fragment-tutorial-with-example-in-android-studio